# How to remove ?/ from URL by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

When I am trying to redirect http://www.example.co.uk/business-cloud-backup to https://www.example.co.uk/business-cloud-backup using this script

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

I am getting this URL https://www.example.co.uk/?/business-cloud-backup. I need to remove this ?/ also. I need only
https://www.example.co.uk/business-cloud-backup

My full .htaccess code is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

All I want that https://www.example.co.uk/?/cloud-backup-services this will be redirected into https://www.example.co.uk/cloud-backup-services

Comment: Yes did this..but still opening this https://www.example.co.uk/?/cloud-backup-services. where I need https://www.example.co.uk/cloud-backup-services. How to remove this ?/

Comment: Rules appears to be fine. You may enable & check rewrite logs.